# EOA transfer and OPCODEs

Tags: transactions, evm, opcode, eoa

I'm doing some research on how the transactions are made in Ethereum.
I got reading the code of Geth and the Yellow Paper that a Smart Contract `method` call with a value on the payload will transfer ETH from your account to the SC, and you can read the `value` through `msg.value`, which under the hood is a CALLVALUE OpCode.

My question is, is this CALLVALUE opcode used in more places? specifically, I would like to know if this is used in transfers between EOAs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

CALLVALUE just return the amount of ether transferred. It doesn't change the balance of the contract.

The opcode CALL is used to transfer ether amounts to another contract or EOA.